# Cannot resolve symbol 'opcfoundation'

Tags: android, opc-ua

I want to implement an OPC-UA client in an Android App.
I found this project on Git, where an OPC-UA client is implemented. When I import it to Android Studio and run it, it works fine.

However I am not able to import anything from org.opcfoundation in my own project. (For example `import org.opcfoundation.ua.core.ApplicationDescription;`). The error I get is simply `Cannot resolve symbol 'opcfoundation'`.

In the sample project in `build.gradle` I also did not find any dependencies.
Is there any way of importing dependencies that I am not aware of yet?

Comment: Which Github demo working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone else who like me does not know: You can also import library by adding the .jar files to the lib folder of your project (go to project view if you don't see it) and importing these files in the .graddle file.